# How to add Tkinter support for PIL Python library

Tags: python, compilation, python-imaging-library, tkinter

Okay, well supposedly PIL is supposed to be able to work with Tkinter automatically, but mine is not. I found this text file in the Imaging directories Tk directory.

> ```
> Using PIL With Tkinter 
>
> Starting with 1.0 final (release candidate 2 and later, to be
> precise), PIL can attach itself to Tkinter in flight.  As a result,
> you no longer need to rebuild the Tkinter extension to be able to
> use PIL.
>
> However, if you cannot get the this to work on your platform, you
> can do it in the old way:
>
> * Adding Tkinter support
>
> 1. Compile Python's _tkinter.c with the WITH_APPINIT and WITH_PIL
>    flags set, and link it with tkImaging.c and tkappinit.c.  To
>    do this, copy the former to the Modules directory, and edit
>    the _tkinter line in Setup (or Setup.in) according to the
>    instructions in that file.
>
>    NOTE: if you have an old Python version, the tkappinit.c
>    file is not included by default.  If this is the case, you
>    will have to add the following lines to tkappinit.c, after
>    the MOREBUTTONS stuff:
>
>   {
>       extern void TkImaging_Init(Tcl_Interp* interp);
>       TkImaging_Init(interp);
>   }
>
>    This registers a Tcl command called "PyImagingPhoto", which is
>    use to communicate between PIL and Tk's PhotoImage handler.
>
>    You must also change the _tkinter line in Setup (or Setup.in)
>    to something like:
>
>    _tkinter _tkinter.c tkImaging.c tkappinit.c -DWITH_APPINIT
>   -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -ltk8.0 -ltcl8.0 -lX11
> ```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to do any of this, and I couldn't find any guides online. Can someone please walk me through how I compile Python's _tkinter.c with the flags set and so on?

Answer (score 0):

What versions of Python and PIL are you using (and on what platform, etc)?  All reasonably recent versions should already support all of these required options (with setup.py as well as Modules/Setup.dict) -- e.g., including tkappinit.c etc -- so it's particularly hard to know what to suggest "in a vacuum".  Also, how to compile things (supposing you do need to) can be very platform-dependent, so in case you do need any recompiling (unlikely as that may be), knowing your platform can be important.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6.5 and PIL 1.1.7 (the latest PIL) on Mac OS X 10.6. I installed PIL using setup.py, and PIL works except for when I try to use it with Tk.

Comment: It's weird because I also have a desktop Mac running OS X 10.6 and Python 2.6, and PIL with Tk works fine on that. (The computer it's not working on is a macbook pro). I installed PIL differently on the desktop than I did on the macbook, but unfortunately I don't really remember how I did it.

Comment: Are you using 2.6.5 on the desktop too, or a different 2.6 such as the one Apple supplies?  Maybe that explains it...